# Exception in thread django-main-thread django

Tags: python, django, pycharm

Whenever running the server the following exception is poping up.
Exception in thread django-main-thread:

Following are the respective Traceback.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\sarathmahe024\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 954, in _bootstrap_inner
     self.run()
  File "C:\Users\sarathmahe024\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 892, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\sarathmahe024\Downloads\website\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\sarathmahe024\Downloads\website\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 118, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "C:\Users\sarathmahe024\Downloads\website\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 442, in check
    raise SystemCheckError(msg)
django.core.management.base.SystemCheckError: SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS:
web.Profile.image: (fields.E210) Cannot use ImageField because Pillow is not installed.
        HINT: Get Pillow at https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/ or run command "python -m pip install Pillow".

System check identified 1 issue (0 silenced).
```

I had already installed the pillow but its showing error in importing ImageField.

Please let me know if you have any idea regarding this. Thanking you in advance.

Comment: Make sure you are installing Pillow in the same virtual environment in which you run Django.

Comment: yes . it's already there.